# How to get the number of languages a Wikipedia page is available in? (SPARQL query)

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I'm trying to have a list of Italian books from the 1980 on and the number of Wikipedia pages their original Wikipedia page has been translated into, for instance I would like to have:

```
Book, number
The name of the Rose, 5
```

Where 5 is the number of languages The Name of the Rose has been translated into in Wikipedia, for instance there is an English wiki page, a Dutch one, a Spanish one, a French one, a Greek one.

Here is the query so far:

```
SELECT ?item ?label 
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?type {wd:Q571 wd:Q7725634}  # book or literary work
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  ?item wdt:P577 ?date FILTER (?date > "1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) . #dal 1980
  ?item rdfs:label ?label filter (lang(?label) = "it")
  ?item wdt:P495 wd:Q38 .


}
```

I get the list of books, but I can't find the right property to look for.

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?label (count(?lang) as ?numWikipediaLanguages)
WHERE
{
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
  VALUES ?type {wd:Q571 wd:Q7725634}  # book or literary work
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  ?item wdt:P577 ?date .
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
  FILTER (?date > "1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) . #dal 1980
  ?item rdfs:label ?label filter (lang(?label) = "it")
  ?item wdt:P495 wd:Q38 .
  
  ?article schema:about ?item ;
              schema:inLanguage ?lang ;
              schema:isPartOf [ wikibase:wikiGroup "wikipedia" ] .
  

} group by ?item ?label`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering, I get only about 400 items but they must be more...

Comment: which ones would you say are missing for examples? I mean in the end it depends on the data in Wikidata

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually get *The Name of the Rose* in your example? Because its date of publication is set to `1980` (which is `= 1980-01-01` for our purposes), I had to change your query to a `>=` comparison.

Then, using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` as mentioned in the comment gets you what you want. But if you really just need the number of sitselinks, there is a shortcut that may be useful. It was added because that number is often used as a good proxy for an item's popularity, and using the precomputed number is vastly more efficient than getting all links, grouping, and counting.

```
SELECT ?book ?bookLabel ?sitelinks ?date WHERE {
  VALUES ?type { wd:Q571 wd:Q47461344 wd:Q7725634 }
  ?book wdt:P31 ?type;
        wdt:P577 ?date;
        wdt:P495 wd:Q38;
        wikibase:sitelinks ?sitelinks.
  FILTER((?date >= "1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) && (?date < "1981-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it,en". }
}
```

[Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fbook%20%3FbookLabel%20%3Fsitelinks%20%3Fdate%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Ftype%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ571%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ47461344%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ7725634%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fbook%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ftype%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fdate%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP495%20wd%3AQ38%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Asitelinks%20%3Fsitelinks.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%28%3Fdate%20%3E%3D%20%221980-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%20%26%26%20%28%3Fdate%20%3C%20%221981-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22it%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Note that the values may slightly differ from the version with group & count because here sites such as `commons` or `wikiquote` are also included.